# Display search results in jQGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, search, jqgrid

I have asp.net mvc 3.0 application.

I want to create view with a couple of inputs and by submitting search values on controller than i want to display search results in jQGird.

Is there any samples or how could i do that?

update

I see that jQGrid has search features by default, should i better use that rather that separate fields?

Comment: Look at the UPDATED part of [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644) and download the demo VS2010 project from [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemoVS2010.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer, it might help you:

[JqGrid and Search form - ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127541/jqgrid-and-search-form-asp-net-mvc/8460010#8460010)

You can use jqGrid's default search features, but sometime you might want to use a customized layout, built by you, which is what the link above demonstrates.